# Mozilla Firefox Extension Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am new to Firefox extension. I am not able to understand the following piece of code. Can anyone please explain this.

var httpRequestObserver =

{

```
observe: function(subject, topic, data)
                    .
                    .
```

}

I want to know what does "httpRequestObserver" and "observe" function does. I am also searching for tutorials for the same, but couldn't find any. It will be really helpful if someone can provide tutorials for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers) at MDN which has sample code related to your example.

Your `httpRequestObserver` is an object that will probably later be "registered" to the application Observer Service for notifications on a specific `topic`, for example `http-on-modify-request`.

Each time a request is sent, the Observer Service will loop through the list of registered objects for the `http-on-modify-request` topic and will call their `observe` method. This gives the objects a chance to do something with the request before it is actually sent, like adding a custom HTTP header.

Comment: Hey, I am confused about one thing. While intercepting the "POST" request before it is sent to the server, do we have to set the request method to "POST" again explicitly?

Comment: Hey, now I am looking at the `http-on-examine-response` topic. There, I come across `TracingListener()`, which i don't know what it does. Can you please provide some links or tutorial for the same?

Comment: About POST requests, you do not have to do anything. You are just modifying the original nsIHttpChannel object that will be used to send the request.

Comment: Regarding TracingListener, when the response comes back from the server, it will normally be sent to the original listener (the code making the request). You can intercept the response by registering to "http-on-examine-response", but if you want to play with the content you have to create your own listener and replace the original listener with it. After you are done modifying the content, you call back in the original listener. Check [this link](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/) for examples.